# Regex remove 'by' from a string

Tags: python, regex

Update 2: https://regex101.com/r/bE5aWW/2

Update: This is what I can come up with so far, https://regex101.com/r/bE5aWW/1/, but need help to get rid of .

Case 1

```
\n                                \n                                   by name name\n                                \n
```

Case 2

```
\n                                \n                                   name name\n                                \n
```

Case 3

```
by name name
```

Case 4

```
name name
```

I would like to select the name part from the above strings, i.e. `name name`. The one I came up with, `(?:by)? ([\w ]+)` donesn't work when there are spaces before `by`.

Thanks

Codes from regex101

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?:by)? ([\w ]+)"

test_str = ("\\n                                \\n                                   by Ally Foster\\n                                \\n                            \n\n"
    "\\n                                \\n                                   Ally Foster\\n                                \\n                            \n\n"
    "by name name\n\n"
    "name name")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Show code. It matters very much how you apply a regex.

Comment: What does `\n` represent here? Is it a new line or a literal "\n"?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed line break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using

```
re.findall(r'\b(?!by\b)[^\W\d_]+(?: *(?:, *)?[^\W\d_]+)*', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C6oROu/1). In Python 2, you will need to pass `re.U` flag to make all the shorthand character classes and the word boundary Unicode aware. To also match tabs rather than just spaces, replace spaces with `[ \t]`.

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!by\b)` - the next word cannot be `by`
- `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more letters
- `(?: *(?:, *)?[^\W\d_]+)*` - a non-capturing group that matches 0 or more occurrences of:

  - `*` - zero or more spaces
  - `(?:, *)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and 0+ spaces
  - `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more letters.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:by )?(\b(?!by\b)[\w, ]+\S)
```

My final version, which also won't select strings only have `by`